# How do you roll back gatsby versions?

Tags: command-line-interface, gatsby

A co-worker pulled a gatsby repo from one of our projects and ran some command he shouldnt have. Now he has gatsby 2 installed on a gatsby 1 project. needless to say, everything broke.

Oddly, I am having a hard time finding how to roll back on his local machine.

Does anyone know how to roll back gatsby versions?

Comment: Have you tried removing .cache, node_modules then reinstall with gatsby 1?

Comment: I think it's the reinstall with gatsby 1 thats the hang up. Im looking for a command to run that specifically installs gatsby 1 but all the documentation looks like its for v2

Comment: oh, perhaps he upgraded gatsby-cli by mistake? Have you tried uninstall gatsby-cli globally and reinstall it with `npm i -g gatsby-cli^1.1.41-13`?

Comment: @DerekNguyen - that's got to be it based on what we get back in version results. You can add that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: ah nice, i've post as an answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When downgrading from gatsby 2 to 1, make sure to check global version of `gatsby-cli` as well (latest version of gatsby-cli 1 is [1.1.41-13](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-cli/v/1.1.41-13))

```
#npm
npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli
npm install -g gatsby-cli^1.1.41-13

#yarn
yarn global remove gatsby-cli
yarn global add gatsby-cli^1.1.41-13
```

I wish there were a way tolock global package's version, but it seems to be currently impossible.

Comment: Pretty sure that was it. He read a warning and updated without confirming with the rest of us. It resulted in a non-compiling break that gave this error, in case this happens to anyone else: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost 
If anyone else believes this is an incorrect assumption they can leave an answer as well

Comment: The carrot didn't work for me to specify version. I had to use @ to install a specific version of Gatsby.

e.g.

`npm install -g gatsby-cli@3.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume he used git to pull the repo in the first place? If so just checkout the changes in package manager files like `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` are rebuild.

Comment: Actually we deleted the whole local and pulled from git again. The package is the same, and we removed the lock file before running npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 and this was sufficient to downgrade `gatsby`:

`npm install -g gatsby-cli@3.4.0`

Instead of `3.4.0` you can use whichever version you want. To verify whether it worked, just type `gatsby --version` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows 10, after `npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli` (and also tried `yarn global remove gatsby-cli`. )

I could execute the command `gatsby -v` anyway, with the same version than before.

I delete the binaries `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\gatsby.*`.

Then, the command didn't found.

```
> npm install -g gatsby-client@latest-v2
> gatsby -v
Gatsby CLI version: 2.19.3
Gatsby version: 2.13.39
```

It's run

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo npm uninstall -g gatsby-cli 
sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli@1.1.41-13
```